# A problem of pagenumbering in LaTeX

Tags: page-numbering, xepersian

I have a problem with pagenumbering in my document.
when I use `\pagenumbering{roman}` for appendix, the page before the first page of appendix (last page of reference), has the number (`I`) and pagenumbers of appendix starts from `1`. in other word it has this numbering `1 2 3 ...`

What should I do?

```
\appendix

\pagenumbering{roman}

\include{app1}
```

PS: I'm using `xepersian`.

Comment: Insert `\pagenumbering{roman}` inside the file `app1`, maybe after `\chapter{}` if there is one.

Comment: @Sigur Thank you very much. it works fine:)

Comment: Welcome to TeX SE! You can also try `\clearpage` or `cleardoublepage` prior to changing the page numbering.

Comment: You also can use the `apptools` package and wite in your preamble `AtAppendix{\pagenumbering{roman}}.`

Comment: @cfr My impression is that you have the correct answer

Comment: @egreg Not according to the OP. That says Sigur's suggestion solved the problem.

Comment: @cfr That works because `\include` issues `\clearpage`. But it's a bad workaround, in my opinion. One should ***always*** do `\cleardoublepage` before `\pagenumbering`.

Comment: @egreg Well, OK. I posted an answer. I would do `\clearpage` or `\cleardoublepage` were I to ever change page numbering, just because that works well when I'm changing the page style.

Answer (score 4):

The trick is to `\clearpage` or `\cleardoublepage` before switching the numbering, so that the final page in the previous numbering system gets numbered *before* the numbering is switched.

Since `\cleardoublepage` reduces to `\clearpage` in a single-sided document, simply `\cleardoublepage` is sufficient.

The following code should do the right thing:

```
Stuff on last page before appendices. 

\cleardoublepage

\pagenumbering{roman}
\appendix   

\include{app1}
```